# How to make my mirror tool work again?

Tags: krita

I was inking a piece and wanted to use the mirror tool. However,when i turned on the vertical one and did a stroke,the stoke did not appear on the other side. I tried again with the horizontal one but it still did not work. I even went as far as to create a new canvas and still the stroke won't appear.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are experiencing a bug, it can be your version it is around 4.1.1 nowadays, if possible talk with developers in https://krita.org/en/irc/. You can use the **multibrush tool (Q)** if it is working for you. It have a lot of extra features and some disadvantages (traditional mirror work with all the tools as it is not a tool itself). You just need to adjust it from **simetry** to **mirror**

The tool icon will look like this: [image]

[image]